# How to pass #httpServletRequest to a bean method in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass the httpServletRequest object to a bean inside thymeleaf but the result is always null inside my method.

this works

```
<span th:text="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}">Real Path</span>
```

and so does this

```
<span th:text="${@myBean.analyzeString('XXXXXXX')}">Test String</span>
```

but when I try to pass #httpServletRequest into a method that accepts that data type it always ends up null inside the method. For example the following throws a null pointer exception.

```
<span th:text="${@myBean.analyzeRequest(#httpServletRequest)}">Request Placehodler</span>
```

Comment: the #httpServletRequest and similar web context expressions provide access to these objects but I doubt if you can use them to pass references.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to pass the request URI, you can try `<span th:text="${@myBean.analyzeRequest(#httpServletRequest.requestURI)}">Request Placeholder</span>`.